How to adjust the height of superscripts of two letters in the equation
In the tex code $n^{\{\mu} \gamma^{\nu\}}_{T}$, the height of the superscripts in $n$ are different with these in $\gamma$, the subcript of $\gamma$ may cause this problem, it looks like this:

Question: How to adjust the superscripts to make sure that their height are same? you can also adjust the positon or size of the subcript if it is necessary. Thanks very much.

Welcome to tex.sx.  The code you show can't possibly produce that image.  At the very least, the output braces require \{...\}, and the backslashes aren't there.  Please add a small compilable example that produces the questioned output. Then someone can diagnose it reliably.  Our crystal balls aren't in good working order.

Thanks very much for your comment, and I just added {...} in the equation.

You can try $ n^{\{\mu}_{\vphantom{T}} \gamma^{\nu\}}_{T}$, but it looks a bit weird to me with the braces used like that.


Thanks very much for your answer, it looks much better compared with the former one.

We may also try this, $ n^{{\mu}{\vphantom{T}} \gamma^{\nu}}{\scriptscriptstyle{T}}$, and the subscript looks smaller.
